# How to set text color QTableView with QFileSystemModel in Qt?

Tags: qt, qtableview, qfilesystemmodel, qitemdelegate

I use Qtableview to show file and folder (only show icon, filename, size).
I want to paint text color(all text in row) for a few specific files.

Eg: file starts with 'ABC' is gray; 'XYZ' is red,...

Comment: I would derive a new QStyledItemDelegate, override `paint` and change the `.palette` option on the way.

Comment: It may set text color  for any row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to use [`QIdentityProxyModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qidentityproxymodel.html) and override a `data` method for necessary [**roles**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum). For example:

```
QVariant MyProxy::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
  // Whatever you want in condition:
  if ( sourceModel()->data(index, Qt::TextRole).toString() == "SomeFile.txt" )
    switch( role )
    {
    case Qt::ForegroundRole: return Qt::Red;
    case Qt::BackgroundRole: return Qt::Blue; // or any brush, etc
    default:
      break;
    }

  return sourceModel()->data(role);
}

//...
MyProxy proxy = new MyProxy{};
proxy->setSourceModel( yourModel );
view->setModel( proxy );
```

Comment: But when reuse this model, I can't convert QFileSystemModel to use a few function such as filePath,... and show size both is 0 bytes

Comment: Please Keep model unchanged, only change color of row

Comment: @kienbui you don't need to modify anything via proxy model. Do what you want with source model - changes will be applied automatically.

Comment: but when I use proxymodel, size of file set is 0 bytes